Modern C++: Brace initialization not working when inside body of a class constructor?
So I know about uniform initialization in C++, which can be achieved by giving consistent preference to braced initialization over the (many) legacy alternatives available in the language.
Yet, I have noticed that braced initialization does not seem to work when trying to initialize a class data member inside the body of a constructor.
I post an example of this (from a book exercise):
#include <cstdio>

enum class Operation {
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide
};

struct Calculator {
    Calculator(Operation ini_op) {
        my_op{ini_op};
    } 

    char getOperation() {
        switch (my_op) {
            case (Operation::Add): {
                return '+';
            } break;
            case (Operation::Subtract): {
                return '-';
            } break;
            case (Operation::Multiply): {
                return 'x';
            } break;
            case (Operation::Divide): {
                return ':';
            } break;
            default: {
                printf("Input one of the four arithmetic operations");
            }
        }

        return '0';
    }
private:
    Operation my_op;
};

int main(){
    Operation first_op{Operation::Add};
    Calculator my_calculator(first_op);
    printf("My operation is: %c\n", my_calculator.getOperation());
}

This yields
main.cpp: In constructor 'Calculator::Calculator(Operation)':
main.cpp:12:14: error: expected ';' before '{' token
   12 |         my_op{ini_op};
      |              ^

from the compiler (g++? gcc?), see https://onlinegdb.com/kHsf-PYcXE
I understand that all this in practice is of little consequence, because braced initialization works fine when the member is initialized in the initialization list of the constructor and not within its body, as it is good practice to do:
...
struct Calculator{
    Calculator(Operation ini_op): my_op{ini_op} {} 
...

Still, I find this is quite odd, and I wonder if anyone can explain where this behaviour may come from in terms of the logic of the language.

It's not initialization inside the body. Instead it becomes assignment.

You cannot inititialize an object after it's defined except a class member through the member initializer list. So use the member initializer list.

So you guys are saying that default constructor initialises my_op to undefined, then custom constructor assigns to it the value ini_op inside the body, so it's an assignment and not an initialization?

Important side note: All non-static class members and base classes are initialized before they enter the body of the constructor, making the last chance to initialize anything the Member Initializer List. Get used to the member initializer list. It makes a lot of impossible things possible.

Yes. In this case the default initilization is to do nothing. You can assign in the constructor body with good ol' = or change Calculator(Operation ini_op) { my_op{ini_op}; } to Calculator(Operation ini_op) : my_op{ini_op} { /* do nothing here */ }

Side note: If your course/teaching materials didn't cover the Member Initializer List, don't be too surprised. It rarely is. I routinely joke that the ratio of importance of the member initializer list to the language vs how well it is taught borders on infinity.

can explain where this behaviour may come from in terms of the logic of the language.  The initialization list is where you initialize the base classes and the member variables.  The body of the constructor isn't for initialization.

@user4581301 : i have had to use python for a couple of years and now I am trying to refresh my rusty C++ by going through a book ("C++ crash course"). At this point the author has introduced classes as custom types in the "C++ types" chapter, but is yet to introduce member initialization lists :)

Recommendation: Make sure the book covers at least C++17 (the 2017 C++ Standard revision). There's a lot of really good stuff in C++17 (and C++20 and 23, but 17 is my recommended lowest bar) that you don't want to miss out on.

Mind the distinction between initialization and assignment. For many user-defined types, they are very different things; therefore syntax and semantics are different.

@user4581301 it was a choice between this and "A tour of C++", as they are the best reviewed C++ books fully teaching the language in modern standards. "C++ crash course" first came out in 2019 and includes C++17, so no concepts and ranges, yet it still is a whopping 700+ pages

Just the two lines Operation my_op; and my_op{ini_op}; would reproduce your error.  my_op{ini_op}; is not valid C++ syntax after you have created my_op.

When spinning up a new hire I've been using the last edition of Programming Principles and Practices Using C++ (don't have a copy of the new edition; it looks to replace the need for Tour) and then A Tour of C++ to bring in the new stuff. I don't know Crash Course worth beans, but if it covers C++17 it might be OK. That said, it looks like they skipped the Member Initializer list. https://www.learncpp.com/ is a good free resource.

The error does not match the shown code.

@user4581301 : glad to see learncpp.com is back being free

@3CxEZiVlQ it does: just click the onlinegdb.com link i provided to verify

I can't find {my_op{ini_op};} in the question. The linked code does not match the shown code. Please post a [mre].

@3CxEZiVlQ the linked code is the same as posted except for the constructor being a one-liner which is cosmetic

@user4581301 since you were curious, in C++ Crash Course member initialization lists are introduced in the chapter on references& and pointers*, which is next to the chapter in which types and classes were introduced. The stated reason for the decision to bring them up now, is that - with constness also being introduced in this chapter - member initialization lists are able to initialize const member variables in a constructor, without the need of having to declare the constructor const.
